# Symfony Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime

I know this seems to be a pretty common type of error but after looking on SO, I couldn't find a fix to my problem.
So I have an entity which holds several DateTime fields. They are declares as `DATETIME` in my MySQL database.
Here's my entity only the part of interest

```
 /**
    * @Doctrine\Column(name="dateOuvertureDossier", type="datetime", nullable=false)
    * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le date est obligatoire.")
    */
    private $dateOuvertureDossier;
/**
* @Doctrine\Column(name="premiereDateEvaluation", type="datetime", nullable=false)
* @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le date est obligatoire.")
*/
private $premiereDateEvaluation;

/**
* @Doctrine\Column(name="deuxiemeDateEvaluation", type="datetime", nullable=true)
*/
private $deuxiemeDateEvaluation;

/**
* @Doctrine\Column(name="troisiemeDateEvaluation", type="datetime", nullable=true)
*/
private $troisiemeDateEvaluation;

/**
* @Doctrine\Column(name="quatriemeDateEvaluation", type="datetime", nullable=true)
*/
private $quatriemeDateEvaluation;
```

And here's my form only the part of interest

```
 $builder ->add('dateOuvertureDossier', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
                'input' => 'datetime'
            ))
            ->add('premiereDateEvaluation', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
                'input' => 'datetime'                
            ))
            ->add('deuxiemeDateEvaluation', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'input' => 'datetime'                
            ))
            ->add('troisiemeDateEvaluation', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'input' => 'datetime'                
            ))
            ->add('quatriemeDateEvaluation', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'input' => 'datetime' ))
```

And here's an example of what I'm trying to do in my controller

```
 if($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier = $form->getData();

            if($miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getUtilisateur() != null && 
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getCompagnieAssurance() != null &&
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getVilleClient() != null &&
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getNumeroDossierAssurance() != null &&
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getNomClient() != null &&
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getDateOuvertureDossier() != null &&
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getPremiereDateEvaluation() != null &&
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getGaa() != null &&
               $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getEtat() !=  null
              )
            {
```

**Error :** Call to a member function format() on string

It seems that Symfony is comfused and thinks I want the date stored as a string but I can't figure out why.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check if the method `getDateOuvertureDossier` whether it is returning a `string` or a `\DateTime`?

Comment: When setting the setDateOuvertureDossier, should be populated with a dateTime object, not string..Regards

Comment: @AlvinBunk , Yes, I have tried returning a new DateTime object in the getter like such `new DateTime($this->DateOuverture)` I get the following error : DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given, which leads me to believe that yes, the getter is returning a DateTime object

Comment: @Albeis same thing with the setter, `public function setPremiereDateEvaluation($premiereDateEvaluation) { $this->premiereDateEvaluation = new \DateTime($premiereDateEvaluation); return $this; }` It says that `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: In the above `setPremiereDateEvaluation()` setter, is `$premiereDateEvaluation` a string? The error message says that you are passing in a `object`. Can you check this?

Comment: I never call the setter myself, the object is built by from the form->getData() method. In the form I specified that I wanted it to be a datetime. After your suggestion, I changed it to specifiy I wanted it to be a String then I got the following erroe : Unable to transform value for property path "dateOuvertureDossier": Expected a string.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to remove the format() and simply pass the $DateTimeOuvertureDossier ? like this :

```
$DateTimeOuvertureDossier = $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->getDateOuvertureDossier();
if($DateTimeOuvertureDossier != null)
{
     $miseAjourInfoSuiviDossier->setDateOuvertureDossier($DateTimeOuvertureDossier);
}
```

Comment: his is what is known as guessing and can easily lead to down votes.  $DateTimeOuvertureDossier should be a datetime object.  The fact that it is not implies a problem elsewhere.

Comment: I have tried removing the format methods. The only thing now is that all the code I initially posted for the controller is rendered useless. See the code that I will have updated. I dumped the object and it is indeed a DateTime object. Now, the date is set from the form but I still get the error.